# How can i pass nothing or a blank cell to an Optional argument in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up a function so that whether I pass a blank cell or do not even select a cell for the argument it returns the function I am looking for.  Here is my code:

```
Function FinancialsAge(FirstBirthday As Date, BeginningDate As Date, Optional SecondBirthday As Variant) As String

If IsMissing(SecondBirthday) = True Or SecondBirthday = vbNullString Then
    FinancialsAge = Year(BeginningDate - FirstBirthday) - 1900
ElseIf SecondBirthday Then
   FinancialsAge = (Year(BeginningDate - FirstBirthday) - 1900) & "/" & (Year(BeginningDate - SecondBirthday) - 1900)
End If

End Function
```

This code works fine as long as I select a blank cell for the third argument but when I leave the third argument out I get a "#Value!" error in the cell.  Anyway to do this in Excel VBA so that the function works under both circumstances?

Thanks,

Comment: @SiddharthRout, it works for me (on Excel 2007). Your suggestion would yield a different answer to the op's function. Take for example `=FinancialsAge(1st Jan 1980,1st Jan 2000)` = 19 but `=year(1st Jan 2000)-year(1st Jan 1980)` would be 20. (date entered like that to avoid confusion over regional settings)

Comment: @Simon: True... I misunderstood the question. Deleted my comment :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is as simple as adding a default value:

```
Function FinancialsAge(FirstBirthday As Date, BeginningDate As Date, Optional _
    SecondBirthday As Variant = vbNullString) As String
```

You would also be able to remove `IsMissing(SecondBirthday) = True Or` as well then

Comment: + 1 :) @user2985990: I am curious as to why have you declared Function FinancialsAge As `String`?

Comment: Just a word to the wise, be careful with either falsely declaring functions/variables as different types without fully flushing our your code.  If you want to declare something as a STRING but act on it as a DATE, make sure you cast all your variables (cDate, cInt, cStr, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You should try some error catching (just checking for a singular event is fine for a TRUE statement, but there is always the random event you maybe didn't think of that gives you a FALSE/ERROR statement.  I'm not sure all the inputs you could find, but a null OPTIONAL variable to a function gives a 448 error.  Try to think of the different values for your error (including *text*, *negative values*, and *non-dates* and see what the error values are).

```
On Error Resume Next
    If Err.Number <> 448 Then '"OPTIONAL" value is not present
        FinancialsAge = Year(BeginningDate - FirstBirthday) - 1900
    ElseIf Len(SecondBirthday) > 0 Then
       FinancialsAge = (Year(BeginningDate - FirstBirthday) - 1900) & "/" & (Year(BeginningDate - SecondBirthday) - 1900)
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Error trapping should be a last resort. In this case it isn't necessary as there are less clumsy ways of dealing with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Simon1979's answer sort of goes in the right direction, but I would go further and say that if you know you want `SecondBirthday` to be a date (and not some other data type), then you should declare it as a `Date`, not a `Variant`. A Variant leaves the door open for unexpected input data types such as Strings, Objects, whatever, and then you have to add awkward error handling code to deal with those.

I would do this:

```
Private Const NullDate As Date = -657434 ' 1 Jan 100 -- a date you will never use

Function FinancialsAge(FirstBirthday As Date, BeginningDate As Date, _
    Optional SecondBirthday As Date = NullDate) As String

    If SecondBirthday = NullDate Then
        'Presumably no SecondBirthday was specified by the user.
        FinancialsAge = Year(BeginningDate - FirstBirthday) - 1900
    Else
        FinancialsAge = (Year(BeginningDate - FirstBirthday) - 1900) _
            & "/" & (Year(BeginningDate - SecondBirthday) - 1900)
    End If

End Function
```

Now the only "unclean" thing here is the arbitrary choice of value for your `NullDate` constant, which could in principle collide with a legitimate `SecondBirthday` input value. But unless you're studying the finances of the ancient Roman empire, the example I give should be fine; if you *are*, then pick something in the distant future instead, e.g. 2958465 i.e. 31 Dec 9999.

Either way, this is less "unclean" than using a Variant which can potentially lead to multiple issues as described above.